# ffmpeg single source and multiple streaming + multiple image overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

NOTE: The below ffmpeg command lines are just a pseudo lines, not 100% final.

From single source I need to stream 2 different `udp://` stream.
And I need to overlay 2 different png images on each.

Base sample line:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -f dshow -i "video=VideoCaptureDevice:audio=AudioCaptureDevice" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfaac -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1234?pkt_size=1316" -codec:v libx264 s:v 720x480 -codec:a libfaac -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1235?pkt_size=1316"
```

Now I need to overlay 2 separate images in each output.
I tried below lines and failed.

Overlay sample line what I tried:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -f dshow -i "video=VideoCaptureDevice:audio=AudioCaptureDevice" -i "C:\Image1.png" -filter_complex "overlay=100:100" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfaac -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1234?pkt_size=1316" -i "C:\Image2.png" -filter_complex "overlay=500:100" -codec:v libx264 s:v 720x480 -codec:a libfaac -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1235?pkt_size=1316"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -f dshow -i "video=VideoCaptureDevice:audio=AudioCaptureDevice" -i "C:\Image1.png" -i "C:\Image2.png" -filter_complex "split[a][b];[a][1]overlay=100:100[v1];[b][2]overlay=500:100,scale=720:480[v2]" -map "[v1]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfaac -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1234?pkt_size=1316" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfaac -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1235?pkt_size=1316"
```

Comment: Thanks Gyan, I tried your solution and the stream doesn't start.

Comment: ffmpeg -f dshow -i "video=VideoDev:audio=AudioDev" -i "C:\Image1.png", -i "C:\Image2.png" -filter_complex "split[a][b];[a][1]overlay=100:100[v1];[b][2]overlay=500:100,scale=720:480[v2]" -map "[v1]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt:v yuv420p -s:v 720x486 -b:v 1024k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -codec:a libfaac -b:a 128k -strict -2 -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1234?pkt_size=1316" 
-map "[v2]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt:v yuv420p -threads 4 -tune zerolatency -preset:v superfast -s:v 720x480 -codec:a libfaac -b:a 96k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -bt 4097 -r 25 -f mpegts "udp://224.1.1.1:1235?pkt_size=1316"

Comment: Save to files instead and check.

Comment: There was a comma ( -i "C:\Image1.png", -i "C:\Image2.png" ) instead of space. I fixed it and I could see 2 images on 2 streaming. But I could see 3 streaming are playing. One extra "VLC (Direct3D output)" window opening which is not expected. Any clue ?

Comment: That sounds like a player issue. ffmpeg is only sending 2 outputs.

Comment: I could successfully show 2 images on 2 streaming output.
Now the CPU load is too much.
Without image overlay the CPU load is just 10% with images it is 25%
Pls. suggest any trick to reduce CPU load while displaying image overlay.

Comment: Add `-preset:v superfast` to your first output.

Comment: Thanks again Gyan,
I have cross checked both streams using -preset:v superfast.
When I checked single stream, the image overlay eats 10% extra CPU. very bad of ffmpeg. Upsets me...

-codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt:v yuv420p -threads 4 -tune zerolatency -preset:v superfast -profile:v baseline -level 3.1

-codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt:v yuv420p -threads 4 -map "[v2]" -map 0:a -tune zerolatency -preset:v superfast -s:v 720x480